# Can't Loop The Data in Codeigniter HTML Table

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want to create a loop for my database result. But I can't make it work on my VIEW file.

So here's my model:

```
<?php class Dash_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {

                parent::__construct();
                // Loading second db and running query.
            $CI = &get_instance();
            //setting the second parameter to TRUE (Boolean) the function will return the database object.
            $this->db2 = $CI->load->database('db2', TRUE);
        }

        public function query0()
        {
            $query = $this->db2->query("SELECT name FROM table1 ORDER BY date");
            return ($query->result());

        }

        public function query1()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("MY QUERY HERE, RUNS OK");

            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;

        }

        public function query2()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("MY QUERY HERE, RUNS OK");

            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
        }

        public function query3()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("MY QUERY HERE, RUNS OK");

            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
        }

        public function query4()
        {
            $query = $this->db->query("MY QUERY HERE, RUNS OK");

            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
        }

}
```

Let's say that my query works ok, I've tested it on my SQL Server. And then here's my CONTROLLER:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dash_control extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('dash_model');
            $this->load->library('table');
       }

    public function index()
    {
        $tmpl = array (
        'row_start'           => '<tr>',
        'row_end'             => '</tr>',
        'cell_start'          => '<td>',
        'cell_end'            => '</td>',
        );

        $this->table->set_template($tmpl); 

        $data['result0'] = $this->dash_model->query0();
        $data['result1'] = $this->dash_model->query1();
        $data['result2'] = $this->dash_model->query2();
        $data['result3'] = $this->dash_model->query3();
        $data['result4'] = $this->dash_model->query4();

        $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);
    }


}
```

So i have 5 function in my model, the result was supposed to be a LOOP data. After I put the model inside my CONTROLLER, I pass it to my VIEW file like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Transaction Success</th>
    <th>Transaction Failure</th>
    <th>Total Visit</th>
    <th>Total Item</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach (array_combine($result0, $result1, $result2, $result3, $result4) as $row)
    { ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->queryalias0; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->queryalias1; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->queryalias2; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->queryalias3; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->queryalias4; ?></td>                                                   
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The error I got was:

```
Message: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements
```

And:

```
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

The result that I would like to achieve should be like this:

[image]

Thank you guys, for all your help...

Comment: Use `array_merge` instead...

Answer (score 0):

From php.net

> array_combine — Creates an array by using one array for keys and
>   another for its values

```
array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )
```

You using wrong way `array_combine` function. You can try `array_merge` instead

```
foreach (array_merge($result0, $result1, $result2, $result3, $result4) as $row)
```